# minted line number overlapped by tcolorbox frame

Tags: tcolorbox, minted

I want to number my code lines. I am using a `tcolorbox` around the `minted` environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}
     {\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced]}

\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}
   {\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[linenos, breaklines=true, breakbefore=., fontsize=\footnotesize]{c}
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
    printf("hello world");
    printf("hello world");
    printf("hello world");
    printf("hello world");
}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I want to avoid the overlapping between the `tcolorbox` frame and the line numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the default value for minted parameter `numsep`. It fixes the distance between numbers and lines, using a lower value move numbers to the right of border line.

By the way, as an alternative to `minted` environment, you can use a `\newtcblisting` (or `\NewTCBListing`) where `minted` is declared a listing engine. Loading `minted` tcolorboxlibrary, already loads `minted` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[most, minted]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{myminted}{%
    listing engine=minted,
    minted language=c,
    listing only,
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    minted options = {
        linenos, 
        breaklines=true, 
        breakbefore=., 
        fontsize=\footnotesize, 
        numbersep=2mm
    },
    overlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \fill[gray!25] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}
    }   
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}
     {\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced]}

\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}
   {\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[linenos, breaklines=true, breakbefore=., fontsize=\footnotesize]{c}
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
    printf("hello world");
    printf("hello world");
    printf("hello world");
    printf("hello world");
}
\end{minted}

\begin{myminted}
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
    printf("hello world");
    printf("hello world");
    printf("hello world");
    printf("hello world");
}
\end{myminted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: optional language**

You can add optional and mandatory parameters to a `\newtcblisting` command, but take care with this advise from `tcolorbox` documentation:[image]

Therefore I've preferred to declare `myminted` environment with two parameters, one mandatory (the language) and one optional (anything else you want to change in initial definition). An example with the new definition is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[most, minted]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{myminted}[2][]{%
    listing engine=minted,
    minted language=#2,
    listing only,
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    minted options = {
        linenos, 
        breaklines=true, 
        breakbefore=., 
        fontsize=\footnotesize, 
        numbersep=2mm
    },
    overlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \fill[gray!25] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}
    },
    #1   
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myminted}{c}
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
    printf("hello world");
    printf("hello world");
    printf("hello world");
    printf("hello world");
}
\end{myminted}

\begin{myminted}[colframe=red,colback=blue!15,sharp corners]{java}
public class HelloWorld {
  // A 'Hello World' in Java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
\end{myminted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if I want to change the language, what should I do? I mean, if I want to use the same environment for c, java, etc...

Comment: @edkeveked I've updated the answer to include parameters.

Comment: Two or more digit line numbers start to overflow to the left, any way to fix that @Ignasi?

Comment: nvm, I used this to get it to work: `\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\parbox{10pt}{\centering\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}`

Answer (score 3):

With `boxsep` you could set the width of the space between the border and your numbers.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}
{\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced, boxsep=10pt]}

    \AfterEndEnvironment{minted}
    {\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}[linenos, breaklines=true, breakbefore=., fontsize=\footnotesize]{c}
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
printf("hello world");
printf("hello world");
printf("hello world");
printf("hello world");
}
    \end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]